# C++ TR1: What is the proper way to use a uniform distribution to generate a random number in a const method?

Tags: c++, random, tr1, const-correctness, const-cast

I have a simple const method that wants to generate a random number

```
int Object::const_method() const {
    std::tr1::uniform_int<int> uni(0,100);
    // do some calculation
   return result;
}
```

This results in your standard (if templafied) const violation error

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/tr1/random.tcc:910:4:
>   error: passing ‘const
>   std::tr1::mersenne_twister’ as ‘this’ argument
>   of ‘result_type
>   std::tr1::mersenne_twister<_UIntType,
>   __w, __n, __m, __r, __a, __u, __s, __b, __t, __c, __l>::operator()() [with _UIntType = long unsigned int,
>   int __w = 32, int __n = 624, int __m =
>   397, int __r = 31, _UIntType __a =
>   2567483615ul, int __u = 11, int __s =
>   7, _UIntType __b = 2636928640ul, int
>   __t = 15, _UIntType __c = 4022730752ul, int __l = 18,
>   result_type = long unsigned int]’
>   discards qualifiers

Is this doable without a `const_cast` on `this`?

Comment: If your PRNG is a data member, then make it `mutable` or hold a pointer to instead of an object.

Comment: Post your full source code. From the looks of the error, your problem is in the '// do some calculation' part you excluded. Namely the part where you use the _uni_ object.

Comment: btw: you should never use const casting unless you are sure that the variable in question is never written to, otherwise the behaviour is undefined and **WILL** break with optimisation/multi-threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your mersenne_twister object mutable within your class.  Without seeing all your code, (especially the do_something part), we can't be certain, but I'm guessing that you have an object within your class of type merseene_twister which you are using a function of which is not a const function itself.  This is causing the error in your class, because your const function is calling a function on merseen_twister that may change it, violating your const signature.

```
// I'm using this as an example.  Yours may differ
typedef std::mersenne_twister<unsigned int, 32, 624, 
    397, 31, 0x9908b0df, 11, 7, 0x9d2c5680, 
    15, 0xefc60000, 18> MerTwister;

class Object 
{
    public:

    int Object::const_method() const 
    {
       std::tr1::uniform_int<int> uni(0,100);

       // do some calculation using the MerTwister object
       return result;
    }


    private:
    mutable MerTwister twister;
};
```

Comment: @Casey: I'm not sure this is necessarily the best solution here (although it obviously works).  `mutable` is meant to help out in situations where the containing object is logically constant, but implementation requires modification (e.g. reference counting, lazy evaluation).  In the OP's scenario, however, calling `const_method()` really is altering the object in a visible manner (it's non-pure, if you like).  IMHO, the best solution is not to have `const_method()` declared as `const`.

Comment: @Oli: Hm, here is the actual scenario so you can tell me what you think: `const_method` is `Position unoccupied_pos() const`. It returns a random unoccupied position in a 2d plane. It is used to randomly distribute some 2d objects throughout the plane. Seems to me that it doesn't modify any internal state (except the engine), does that not count as logically constant?

Comment: @Casey: I guess it depends on your definition; I would say no, because it's not "referentially transparent".  In other words, if you call it again, you'll get a different answer (the answer you get will depend on how many times you've already called it), which doesn't sound very `const` to me!  See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science).

Comment: I agree with most if not all of what Oli stated.  Based on what you posted, there was no way to know if the obj was logically consistent after the call b/c you hadn't shown all the code.  I'm not sure how I feel as to whether this specific scenario should be deemed logically consistent or not, because the purpose of the function is to be random in the first place.  If you had made the twister a local within the func it would have worked w/o the mutable keyword as a const func and hasn't changed the object at all. I think it depends on how you're using the twister object elsewhere.

Comment: It seems based on what we know that you're using the twister as a helper to the class and it really isn't "part" of the class.  It seems you could make a couple design tweaks to move the twister outside the Object class and into another class which takes an object and returns the random position based on it's attributes.  Granted I am making quite a few assumptions here.